# Как удалить из строки все подстроки из 3-х символов?

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток.

Имеется простая задача: взять строку и удалить из нее все подстроки из 3-х символов. Подстроки начинаются на 'y' и заканчиваются на 'k', и из 'yakjkk', например,  получится 'jkk'.

Правильное решение выглядит так:

```
public String stringCut(String str) {
  String result = "";

  for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
    if (i+2<str.length() && str.charAt(i)=='y' && str.charAt(i+2)=='k') {
      i =  i + 2;
    } else {
      result = result + str.charAt(i);
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Мое решение очень похоже, просто идет от 'если не равно':

```
public String stringСut(String str) {
  String result = "";

  for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
    if (i+2<str.length() && str.charAt(i)!='y' && str.charAt(i+2)!='k') {
      result = result + str.charAt(i);
    } else {
      i = i + 2;
    }
  }

  return result;
}
```

Данный код компилируется, однако выдается лишь пустая строка либо ошибочный результат. С чем это может быть связано?

Благодарю.

Comment: потому что код не идентичный - неправильно инвертировано условие

Comment: Разбирайтесь с булевой алгеброй. В частности с [правилом де Моргана](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B5_%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0)

Comment: Но ведь в прежнем ответе было верно инвертировано условие, ведь так?

Comment: Нет. У вас в первом примере `(a && b && c)`. Вы сделали `(a && not(b) && not(c))`, в ответ пытались написать `(a && not(b) || not(c))`, а согласно правилу де Моргана должно быть инвертировано все `(not(a) || not(b) || not(c))`.

Comment: Пардон, все отлично заработало, на сей раз именно _все_ варианты. Большое спасибо.

Comment: Почему бы просто не использовать регулярное выражение `"yakabc".replaceAll("y.k", "")` ?

Comment: Это конечно самый удобный вариант. Благодарю. Странно что в 'правильном ответе' пошли через цикл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
i+2<str.length()
```

Это условие было не правильно инвертировано

Comment: И `&&` между условиями. В общем-то в комментариях к вопросу уже все было сказано.

Comment: Да, вкупе с `&&` именно так. Большое спасибо.